# README.md for MAVEN project in NetBeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, readme

I want add README.md file for in will be visible and editable in NetBeans 8.2 in Maven Java project type, But when the file lies in th project root it still unvisible in the IDE...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough there is a plugin for it.
See at [github](https://github.com/Chris2011/readmeinprojectview) or at [netbeans portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50171/)
To install it go to *Tools -> plugins -> Available Plugins* and search for readme. Choose plugin called **Display readme files in project view**. You can change which files to show on the *Tools -> options -> Miscellaneous->Display more files* panel:

[image]

**UPDATE 2022:**

Currently, the old NetBeans portal unavailable because it was decommissioned. You can download plugin from [here](https://github.com/Chris2011/readmeinprojectview/releases/tag/1.6.0) and install manually. To install it manually, download the file **readmeinprojectview-1.6.0.nbm** then go to *Tools -> Plugins -> Donwloaded -> Add Plugins*.  Then select the plugin and click Install.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because ***readme.md*** is not part of project code. It is a descriptor file for marking down specific lines and paragraphs to highlight project details and it is used to generate the html summary you see at the bottom of projects on pages like `GitHub`.

It will be visible in the **Files** tab.