# Customizing which files are shown in Netbeans' Project View under Project Files

Tags: java, jenkins, netbeans, lombok

I'm using Netbeans IDE (Version 13) for Java development.
In the projects view Netbeans shows a tab for "Project Files". This usually contains files like `pom.xml`, `settings.xml` and `nb-configuration.xml` for an opened Java project.

Now I have added some custom files in the same folder directory as the aforementioned files, namely a `Jenkinsfile.config` as well as a `lombok.config` file.

I would like Netbeans to show these files under the "Project Files" tab for each project but until now I wasn't able to find a solution for this.

I already added the file type ".config" as a file association for Netbeans and associated it to the MIME type "Properties Files".
Now Netbeans recognizes the files (an even their contents) when in the "Files" view but they are still not shown anywhere in the "Projects" view.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[EDIT]: Ideally I would prefer a solution that doesn't require installing any plugins from sources outside of Apache (or similar).
Maybe it is even possible to just configure Netbeans to show the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download and install plugin **[readmeinprojectview](https://github.com/Chris2011/readmeinprojectview)**, see [here how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59603726/5681468).
Then go to Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Display more files. Add the files you need to show in the Project tab. In your case they are Jenkinsfile and lombok.

[image]

The plugin by default adds the [following files](https://github.com/Chris2011/readmeinprojectview/blob/86348dee34ce23cab18b9545b61421a12f9be8de/src/main/java/de/markiewb/netbeans/plugins/readmeinprojectview/ReadmeNodeFactory.java#L65-L77) to the project tab under the root project node. Without the plugin, NetBeans for Maven-based projects displays ONLY logical folders under the root project node i.e. "Source Packages" or "Project Files"...

Currently you  cannot  put the files you want under the "Project files" node. [Here](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/c084119009d2e0f736f225d706bc1827af283501/java/maven/src/org/netbeans/modules/maven/nodes/ProjectFilesNode.java#L157-L166) is the source code of `NetBeans` for Maven-based project types. As you can see under the "Project files" node goes the following files only:

- `pom.xml`
- `nbactions.xml`
- Files that start with `nbactions-` and end with `.xml`
- `nb-configuration.xml`
- Maven's default `settings.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the lead!
I'm just a little uncomfortable installing a plugin into our development environment that is developed by individuals unknown to me and not maintained by a larger foundation. 
I was hoping there would be a possibility to achieve the integration with just configuring Netbeans to do what I need it to.

Comment: @Daki, I don't think you can achieve what you want without the plugin. If you are unsure about the plugin you can download sources and compile it by yourself. The codebase is small.
Updated the answer - added the link to the source code.  You can see how  NetBeans filters which files are shown under the "Project files" node.

Comment: Thanks for the links! 
Yes, you are probably right, that there is no way without using plugins. I'm going to take a look at the codebase and then probably compile it myself whenever I can find the time.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Obbservation: For adding a file such as `buid.xml` one must add the file in the plugin without its `.xml` extension.  So simply as `build`.