# Adding a file in the "Project Files" list in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I've added a `build.xml` file to my project in order to control the "maven-ant-plugin".

However, Netbeans doesn't list that file in its "Project files" list (next to `pom.xml`, `nbactions.xml`, `settings.xml`, ...). So, I have to go via the "Files" tab and navigate to the project's root. Not impossible but not convenient. I'd like to have all those files grouped together in the "Project" tab.

Is there a way to have Netbeans displaying that `build.xml` file in the "Project files" list ?

Comment: Hi, Ivr123 does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72359069/5681468

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I guess this the way. I've been able to install the plugin but I don't succeed in having my `build.xml` appearing. I will pursue my attempts.

Comment: Finally got it working. I added in the file list `build` instead of `build.xml`.